# Function undefined when used in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use a function inside an event handler but it keeps saying undefined. It works outside of my event handler.

The function I am trying to use is called task_name() . I am trying to use it in the updateTaskName() method.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
function task_name(task_id,category_id,task_name){

    var discussions_base_url = <?=json_encode(base_url().ProjCollabNav::$task_discussions);?>;
    var discussions_link = "<a href=" + discussions_base_url + "/" + task_id + "/" + category_id + ">" + task_name +
        "</a>";

    var updated_task = "<li class='tasks' data-task_id='"+task_id+"'>"+discussions_link+"</li>";


    return updated_task;


}





function updateTaskName(){

        $(document).on("click", ".save_task_name_changes", function () {


            var task_id = $(this).data("task_id");
            var category_id = $(this).data("category_id");
            var task_name  = $(".new_task_name_input[data-task_id='"+task_id+"']").val();

            /*Shows undefined*/
            task_name(task_id,category_id,task_name);

            $(".edit_mode[data-task_id='"+task_id+"']").replaceWith(updatedTaskName);


            return false;
        });



    }
```

Comment: The function `task_name` is "overwritten" by the local variable `task_name`. Use proper naming and the problem will be gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two variables named `task_name`. The global function you define and a local variable in your event handler defined by :

```
var task_name  = $(".new_task_name_input[data-task_id='"+task_id+"']").val();
```

The local variable "hide" the global one. You should rename your local variable to something else and then change the call.

```
var tname  = $(".new_task_name_input[data-task_id='"+task_id+"']").val();
task_name(task_id,category_id,tname);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

You declare task_name variable inside your updateTaskName() method:

```
 var task_name  = $(".new_task_name_input[data-task_id='"+task_id+"']").val();
```

This shadows task_name() method which was declared in global environment.